# Installing Windows Terminal .msixbundle using PowerShell Add-AppxPackage

Tags: windows, installation, powershell, windows-terminal

I'm trying to install [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) on Windows 10 v1803 [build 17134.13.04] where I don't have any admin privileges and Microsoft Store has also been deactivated. I downloaded the `.msixbundle` from the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases) and used the command from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/add-appxpackage?view=win10-ps):

```powershell
add-appxpackage -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3141.0_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle"
```

However, I recieve error:

```powershell
add-appxpackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, Package could not be opened.
error 0x8007007B: Opening the package from location Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3141.0_8wekyb3d8bbwe.msixbundle
failed.

NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] b425a102-b6a8-0001-5add-56b4a8b6d601
in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppxLog -ActivityID b425a102-b6a8-0001-5add-56b4a8b6d601

At line:1 char:1 
+ add-appxpackage -Path ".\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_1.4.3141.0_8wekyb3 ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (C:\Users\Farima...bbwe.msixbundle:String) [Add-AppxPackage], FileNotFoundException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
```

What is the problem and how I can resolve it?

Comment: The error told you where to look on line 4, first sentence in _Note_... what did the Event log [Event Viewer] say? Have you googled the error code [`0x80073CF0`]?

Comment: @JW0914 I did some search but not with the `0x80073CF0` error code. Doing so, [this is](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-winapps-appscat_social/error-code-0x80073cf0-on-microsoft-store-windows/a19d7f60-2d34-4b78-b618-048d724b9f92) the first Google result for me. the solution offered starts with opening CMD in admin mode, which is not possible for me.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to istall UWP apps without Admin privs, as they're installed to `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`, of which only `System` and `TrustedInstaller` have write privs for _(its likely Event Viewer would show this)_

Comment: @JW0914 Is there a `.exe`/`.msi`/... portable version of Windows Terminal?

Comment: No, as UWP apps are `.msixbundle` packages that install to `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`. The package format isn't the issue - the issue is the install location requires Admin privs to write to and there is no way to get around this AFAIK, as doing so would compromise the sandboxing of UWP apps within `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`. The best recourse is to simply ask IT, or whoever admins the machine, to install `wt` for you. _(The only time a program install does not require Admin privs is when it's installed within `%UserProfile%`, e.g. `%LocalAppData%` or `%AppData%`)_

Comment: @JW0914 well, asking the IT people is pointless. I have never succeeded in asking anything. Any chance that I can compile the software in another format myself on a different machine and use a portable executable binary?

Comment: Unlikely - you'll need to research on Microsoft Docs to determine if that's feasible

Comment: “What is the problem and how I can resolve it?” - Without Administrator permissions you don’t; “Is there a .exe/.msi/... portable version of Windows Terminal?” - No; Have the Administrator install the application for you, but since they have disabled the Windows Store, that’s probably something they don’t want to have happen

Comment: @Ramhound so it is impossible to compile the source code in another binary format?

Comment: Windows Terminal is a UWP application.  By the time you make it into a Win32 application, it wouldn’t be Windows Terminal, it would be something else completely.  The amount of work that would take probably isn’t worth it.  You asked if there was a portable version of Windows Terminal, there isn’t one, because it’s a UWP application

Comment: @Ramhound is it due to the language, libraries, or just the build tools? If it is just the compiler and the build tools, that could be done with some reasonable amount of work. but if it is because of the dependencies, or the language itself then, you are right, it will be very difficult.

Comment: You cannot easily make a UWP application into a desktop application.

Comment: Hi. PM on Terminal here. Terminal is not a UWP app - it's actually a Win32 app packaged and delivered in an MSIX installer. The app hosts a XAML Island in which we host all the UI elements. The core Terminal pane itself is actually wrapped in a WinUI control, and the VS team has wrapped TerminalCore as a WPF app for integration into VS2019.

Comment: your command helped me, and worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 10):

The reason you're probably getting that error is because Window Terminal requires Windows 10 v1903 or later.

> Windows Terminal requires Windows 10 1903 (build 18362) or later

https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal#installing-and-running-windows-terminal